# Regex for extracting monetary values

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I have this regex `/[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{3})*,([0-9]{2})?/g` for extracting monetary values from text messages.
It is working nicely when the value is in this format:

> R$ 1,00

However, if the text comes with:

> R$ 1

It doesn't work.

How can I have a regex working in both cases?

Comment: Look, the comma is obligatory in `,([0-9]{2})?`. Make it `(?:,[0-9]{2})?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
/[$R]\s*(\d*,?\d+)?\b/g
```